# Averages of conditional subsets of a dataframe in R to store in new dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset

I'm learning to work with R and I would need some help figuring out how to create a dataframe from averages of subsets of my initial dataframe, based on a condition.

I have a df of ~18000 rows, 9 columns, one being a distance. I want to use conditions on the distance to average the values of the 9 columns. The first subset would correspond to a distance range of 0:2.5, the second one a range of 2.5:5, and so on, every 2.5 meters.

I can make a first subset this way :

```
df1 <- subset(df_ini, df_ini$Distance..m.>0 & df_ini$Distance..m.<2.5)
```

The new dataframe now has 18 rows.

I then need to average the values of each column, store them in a new df and continue to do so for every subset, appending the averages to the same df.

I can't get the right loop(s) to do that, I would really appreciate any ideas/tips.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help you, we need a minimally reproducible sample. Could you provide a bit of the data?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty new to R, but maybe this will give some inspiration. I suggest that you take a look at the dplyr package.

For mtcars:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <-  mtcars %>% filter(mpg >= 10 & mpg <= 20) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean)) 
df2 <- mtcars %>% filter(mpg >=20 & mpg  <= 30) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean))

combined <- rbind(subset, subset2)
```

In your dataset you can filter on ranges of distances. Ideally, you would use a loop to automatically create a range of groups (0:2.5, 2.5:5.0, etc..), like you stated in your post. I don't know how to do that though.